# valueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' while migrate

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I wrote this simple model in django-2 and when I tried to migrate I got

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

```
from django.db import models

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.IntegerField(default='',blank=True)
    passcode = models.IntegerField(default='',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.IntegerField(default='', blank=True)
    passcode = models.IntegerField(default='', blank=True)
    teacher = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Lesson (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cource = models.IntegerField(default='', blank=True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey("Teacher", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Student = models.ManyToManyField(Student)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Score(models.Model):
    score = models.FloatField(default='', blank=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defaults for `IntegerField` and `FloatField` can't be a string.

`default=''` means an empty string.

Change defaults for `IntegerField` and `FloatField` to some number or set `null=True`:

**Example:**

```
# Means it can not be empty and if it received empty, put 0 instead.
score = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True)
```

Or

```
# Means it is okay to be empty.
score = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Also, you probably need to remove migration files for previous changes.

Comment: thanks bro. can you explain why I should remove last migration?

Comment: Migrations files are built with previous changes which is `default=' '` and that stop completing the migrations with new changes. Just try and delete them if you got the error again and if you didn't then no need.